# Python possible to short circuit function call

Tags: python, reflection, inspect

I am building a function to construct objects with set attributes (similar to a namedtuple); however, the output length must be variable.

I would like to build a function that allows the user to append additional attributes through a function call. Importantly, I would like to find a way to 'short-circuit' parameters and am unsure if Python is powerful enough to do this.

To explain take this trivial example:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")
    return False

def bar():
    print("bar")
    return True

if foo() and bar():
    pass
```

Foo's function call returns False, and Bar short-circuits. The output console will only print foo, and **bar is never executed**.

Is there such a way to mimic this behavior with inspection or reflection in respect to function calls. Here is an example with my implementation is shown below:

```
from inspect import stack

cache = {}
def fooFormat(**kwargs):
    caller = stack()[1][3]

    if caller not in cache:
        class fooOut(object):
            def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

            def optional(self, opt, **kwargs):
                if (opt):
                    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
                return self

            def __str__(self):
                return caller + str(self.__dict__)
        cache[caller] = iadsOut
    return cache[caller](**kwargs)

def stdev(nums, avg = None):
    print("\tStdev call")
    if avg is None:
        avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)

    residuals = sum((i - avg)**2 for i in nums)
    return residuals**.5

def stats(nums, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Stats call with verbose")
    else:
        print("Stats call without verbose")

    total = sum(nums)
    N = len(nums)
    avg = total / N

    return fooFormat(
        avg = avg,
        lowerB = min(nums),
        upperB = max(nums)).optional(verbose,
        stdev = stdev(nums, avg))
```

In the function 'stats', the return fooFormat should of course yield avg, lowerB, and upperB; additionally, it should yield std if verbose is set to True. Moreover, the function 'stdev' should NOT be called if verbose is set to False.

```
stats([1,2,3,4], False)
stats([1,2,3,4], True)
```

Of course, a way around this is:

```
if verbose:
    return fooFormat(
        avg = avg,
        lowerB = min(nums),
        upperB = max(nums),
        stdev = stdev(nums, avg))
else:
    return fooFormat(
        avg = avg,
        lowerB = min(nums),
        upperB = max(nums))
```

However, I am hoping there to implement this behavior without a branch.

Comment: What's wrong with a branch? `stdev=stdev(nums, avg) if verbose else None` looks fine to me. Then just make sure `fooFormat` treats `None` the same way as not having it at all.

Comment: Nothing necessarily wrong per say, I just don't want to resort to that solution though because there will likely be many outputs (i.e. 20+ more outputs if verbose). That would require 20 ternary operators, which (besides performance, which might be negligible) is ugly. It might help to explain that I am building this for other engineers and 'cleanliness' is important.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer the shortcutting point, but this is a more efficient way of writing it:

```
out_dic = {                      # these items will always be calculated
   'avg':   avg,
   'lowerB':max(nums),
   'upperB':min(nums)
}
if verbose:                      # this is calculated only if verbose
    out_dic['stdev'] = stdev(nums,avg)

return fooFormat(**out_dic)
```

In other words you can expand a dictionary to the `kwargs`, and add to the dictionary dynamically.

Comment: this is probably the way I will go if I can't find another solution.